# what is the best way to send notifications to specific client when there are some changes?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working with .net core (entity framework core) as a web API and with react in the client-side, I want to send notifications to the user when some new tickets are inserted, 
Note: the tickets are not inserted from the client-side but from the other service 
I hope that is clear.

Comment: Checkout SignalR.

Comment: Easy to use in dotnetcore

Comment: What did you decide to use? Can you update with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSockets and SignalR to push async notifications to clients.

Comment: I used websockets , it is work but  that made many requests (ws not http requests) and if I have a huge number  if users that is will be expensive , I am trying to clarify , sorry if that is not clear

Answer (score 0):

By using SignalR, you can set a "Hub" that all of your clients will listen and when a different client inserted a ticket, you can let your server send the info to those connected ones. It is easy to use especially on dotnet core. This is used for real-time applications which is basically what you are trying to ask for.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I want to notify a spesific client , the Agency wich owns the tickets

Comment: Then that is for you to formulate in your front-end if you should be showing this notification to the connected user.

Comment: SignalR itself won't know if the connected client is the Agency, you must identify it in your code.